# What is wrong with this .command file?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal, command-prompt

This is my script to automate the git push of my static blog. 
When I run each command one by one in the Terminal, it works. Do I need to add delays, maybe it's going too fast. The pelican command (static website generator) takes quite a lot of time (2 seconds). Is the rest of the script crashing during that?

```
    #!/bin/sh
    dropbox
    cd blog
    pelican . -s /Users/Paul-Arthur/Desktop/Desktop/Dropbox/blog/pelican.conf.py -t subtle
    cd output
    git add . 
    git commit -m 'commit'
    git push
```

Updated: Sorry, yeah dropbox is a custom command in my bash_profile (this is not the problem, it works I know ;)  ). 
Sadly, when I click my script, it executes (but does not work) extremely quickly so I cannot  see the errors.

Here is the output from the calepin command. The errors are normal and I expect it to run with that. Do you think that this is the problem? If so what can I do?

```
    familys-imac:blog Paul-Arthur$     pelican . -s /Users/Paul-Arthur/Desktop/Desktop/Dropbox/blog/pelican.conf.py -t subtle

    ERROR: Skipping ./articles/aboutme.md: impossible to find informations about 'title'
    ERROR: Skipping ./articles/static_sites.md: impossible to find informations about 'title'
    familys-imac:blog Paul
```

Comment: Since a new command will wait for the preceeding command to finish, no need to worry about adding delays in general.

Comment: What results are you getting? Errors? Can you show them in detail (edit your post)?

Comment: Is "dropbox" an interactive command?

Comment: In scripts it's always recommended to use the full path to commands (or make sure to the set the $PATH variable).  As @art-swri wrote, please post the errors you get.  Is the pelican output generated after the script has run?  What does the git log say?

Comment: updated post to reflect comments

Comment: Don't click the script to run it, run it as a command from the terminal, that way you'll see the output. Without that information it's blind guesswork trying to figure out what your issue is. One such blind guess though, is that you're making assumptions about what the current working directory is by using relative path names in "cd blog" and "cd output". You shouldn't rely on the current working directory having a specific value when you write scripts, as they could be run from anywhere. (The working directory is _not_ necessarily the same directory as the script lives in.)

Comment: ok fixed,chmod +x and a few other things made this work

Comment: Reply to your question, and accept its response please.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the « `cd` » command, since it's not a command, it is a builtin from the shell, and doesn't act like a command.

To debug it, try adding «`pwd`» command inside your script before and after the «`cd`» line, to be sure the working directory has change.

It could also be due to the shell you are using, in the shebang (first line of your script), you are using the /bin/sh script. Is it the good one ? When you do it in your shell, you are maybe using another like bash, dash, zsh etc.

To determine that, type that in your current shell :

```
which `echo $0`
```

You will get an answer like :

```
/bin/bash
```

or something like this. Use this in your shell script :

```
#!/bin/bash
```

And try again your script.

Good luck with your project.